# How to click on the image through Selenium using Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I've been trying to select one image tag, however, since it doesn't have any name and id I'm having trouble while doing the same.

HTML:

```
<tr __gwt_row="0" __gwt_subrow="0" class="GPBYFDECG">
<td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG GPBYFDEEG datagridCellStyle">
    <div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-29">
        ACD DETAILS NEW
    </div>
</td>
<td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG datagridCellStyle">
    <div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-30">
        ACD Details
    </div>
</td>
<td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG GPBYFDEOG datagridCellStyle">
    <div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-31" tabindex="0">


        //IMAGE THAT I NEED TO SELECT AND CLICK
        <img onload="this.__gwtLastUnhandledEvent=&quot;load&quot;;" src="http://172.00.00.00:8080/demoreports/DemoReportsApp/clear.cache.gif" style="width:25px;height:23px;background:url(http://172.00.00.00:8080/demoreport/DemoReportsApp/0210CFCB6CBE82D7E9FAC82D9F901495.cache.png) no-repeat -333px 0px;" border="0">
    </div>
</td>
```

Code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@onload="this.__gwtLastUnhandledEvent=&quot;load&quot;;"]').click()
```

Above code doesn't work.
Is there any other way, I can click() on this img as it generates javscript rendered reports.

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: Try `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[starts-with(@onload, "this.__gwtLastUnhandledEvent=")]').click()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is a dynamic element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *ElementToBeClickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) as solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.datagridCellStyle img[onload*='gwtLastUnhandledEvent'][src*='demoreports/DemoReportsApp/clear']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[contains(@class, 'datagridCellStyle')]//img[contains(@onload, 'gwtLastUnhandledEvent') and contains(@src, 'demoreports/DemoReportsApp/clear')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```